# how do i know if my app is featured in the iTunes app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Obviously there are many iTunes app stores and many different sections to be featured in, so how do you know if your app is featured in the app store? How would I as an American know that my app is featured in the What's Hot Entertainment section of the Australian store? Is there some central place to check?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sign up for a free account at [AppLyzer](http://www.applyzer.com/). They provides free daily monitoring of all the various app stores so you can quickly see your rankings as well as if you're featured in any of them. You may also sign up for pro features, but just for checking if you're featured the free account will do fine.

I signed up myself a few weeks back and was surprized to see that I had recently been featured 3 times in the US store as "What's Hot".

Comment: Just for balance: www.appfigures.com supplies a similar service.

Comment: @Tommy: I can't figure out how to make appFigures work without turning my iTunes Connect account credentials over to them. That's just not going to happen.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm not connected to either service — though I think you're right that the primary focus of App Figures is the collection of sales data, which necessitates having an iTunes Connect login (of course, you can set one up with only that level of access); international rank tracking is secondary and doesn't work standalone.

Comment: where exactly is this?

Answer (score 7):

http://www.appannie.com tells you exactly how many positions you are featured in and where.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit long winded .. but you could open iTunes and change the country (click on the flag, bottom right) ...

Once you're switched stores you can check out where you app is, if it's being featured etc, in the chosen country.

Just remember to switch it back when you're done